# 'Smart' grouping in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need somehow to group my rows by specific condition

```
|id | address    | last_name | Count of purchases | customer_number |
|1  | de Berlin  | name_1    | 1                  | 11111           |
|2  | de Berlin  | name_2    | 1                  | 12345           |
|3  | de Berlin  | name_1    | 1                  | 12345           |
```

So the problem is that I need to group by `address` AND `last_name` BUT in this case row with ID = 2 will not be in set because it has different last_name BUT it shares the same customer_number number with row with ID = 3. Can I do it somehow with one query?

So basically I want to receive something like

```
select SUM(Count_of_purchases), array_agg(last_name), array_agg(customer_number)
from table
group by f(address, last_name, customer_number)
```

```
| 3 | {name_1, name_2} | {11111, 12345} |
```

Comment: Your example only returns one row.  Is that always the case?  If not, then under what conditions would it return more than one?

Comment: @jjanes If there were a customer with name_3 and customer_number 10000, there'd be 2 rows.

Comment: @sudo is right, I need somehow to group by address and last_name but also include in match set rows which shares the same customer_number, something like 

`collection. group_by { |row_1, row_2| row_1.last_name == row_2.last_name || row1.customer_number == row2.customer_number }
`